# Is it possible to find information on apache_mod_php processes under /proc?

Tags: apache-2.2, process, metrics, mod-php

I have an apache2 server with apache2_mod_php installed.

Is there a way for me to determine **from the information under /proc** (or elsewhere), which apache processes are currently executing the php module, and which VirtualHost is responsible?  Perhaps even how much processing power is consumed (in some metric or another)?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no easy way to do this.  The best you can do is fire up `mod_status` and watch what's going on (`ExtendedStatus On` will give you a list of all the URLs being serviced).

If you have a desperate, pressing need to be able to account for PHP processing time, I would look at moving PHP processing out to a FastCGI pool then enable BSD process accounting so I could track the current and historical resource usage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe OProfile can help you: http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/

But if you are looking for something for billing purposes I doubt it is going to be the right tool for the job.

Cheers